# How to Include a HTML File in AMP

Tags: amp-html

I wonder if there is a way to include elements of the design that are repeated across every page on the site. Some examples of site elements that would be found across every page as the header area where the logo resides, the navigation, and the footer area.

My goal is not to have to correct all sides when I make a change, for example, in the menu.

Or does anyone know another valid way?

Comment: I can't find any way in plain AMP on https://ampbyexample.com/. However, you can always setup AMP with a Ruby project. This is a quick guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIV1SQWSzzI.

Comment: Use the same approach as you use on non-amp pages. For example, in Web Forms project you can use `.master` pages. Of course, you need to `AMP`ify everything.

Comment: Can you give that a little more precise or perhaps an example?

Comment: @Peter: Which technology are you using along with AMP ? like php or asp.net..You can use concept of master pages to repeat HTML across multiple pages. I am afraid this is not possible with plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Include another HTML file in a HTML file using **amp-iframe** tag in AMP

**Put Js in head section**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

**Put iframe code in body section**

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="https://www.example.com/htmlfile.html">
</amp-iframe>
```

> An amp-iframe may not appear close to the top of the document (except for iframes that use placeholder). The iframe must be either 600 px away from the top or not within the first 75% of the viewport when scrolled to the top, whichever is smaller.

For more details please [refer this link](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with plain html in amp but you can achieve this by webpack plugins.You can find more info about this in ampstart.com project.